# Example of function on R with given property

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

I wanted to find example of function with following property: $f(x)=0,\forall x\leq 0$ and $f(x)>0,\forall x>0$
I tried but. I stuck in  infinite differentiablilty. I thought some combination of exponential and integration but not succeed. Any help will be appreciated

Edit:

Comment: Please state the full requirements of the problem. Do you need $f(x)$ to be infinitely differentiable - or is anything else needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & \text{if $x \le 0$} \\
e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}, & \text{if $x > 0$}
\end{cases}$$

Hope that will work.